# How do you turn a question into a community wiki? (and how do you access them)

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I see a lot of 'community' users that appear to both ask questions and answer. How do you create a wiki question, post as a community user, and just generally interact with the 'community wikis'?

A brief look around didnt show any clear ways to do this. Should we make this easier to do?

Answer (score 5):

Community Wiki is an option that is largely deprecated now, so we try to dissuade anyone from this.

The ones you see are historical.

There is nothing to stop you asking a question and then answering it yourself.

If you want to update/edit a community wiki post, you can once you have over 100 rep.

Comment: Oh that's really good to know. Are there alternatives?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by alternatives. What is it you are wanting to do? As things stand now, anyone with enough rep can edit any post.

Comment: Take for example when a question is more of a discussion of best practices or best tools. The question seems nice to have, but it isnt temporally answerable because 'the best' is likely to change.

Comment: Generally we don't. Stack Exchange really isn't suited to discussion. If you have a read of the [about] page, this is described fairly well. Meta.SE has various commentary on the best way to handle temporal change.